# Automatic duplicate/copy of post to a related page in WordPress

Tags: posts, categories, pages, page-attributes, post-duplication

I have a website about introducing softwares and apps. I created pages and so menus (named by categories).

I set my WordPress setting homepage to latest posts. I create posts and give them categories and tags.

I like to have the option to automatically create a copy of content of a post in related page, in which this relation might be its category?

Is there such possibility inside WP or some free plugins?

Thanks.

Comment: Categories automatically get their own page with the posts on it. Go to Posts > Categories and click the View link.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, thanks for your comment. Now as I already created pages and most of them are in menus: for instance my page and menus address are like "www.example.com/software" , however the categories address are "www.example.com/category/software" . To not loose SEO and having problem with addressing and Google search, what can I do now for having that property  in Question (duplicate/copy) here. Should I change the url of pages or the url of categories or should do something else? thanks.

Comment: Just redirect your page URLs to the proper category URLs. Anything else is a waste of effort.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, you mean redirect using some plugin such as "301 Redirects"?